# Как параметризовать запрос в Oracle в части in?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Под капотом `Oracle 11`.

Внутри процедуры формируется запрос и выполняется через `execute immediate`. 
Схематично код выглядит так:

```
declare
  l_sql varcahr2(100);
  l_txt varchar2(100);
Begin
  ...
  loop
    <формируем l_txt с произвольным количеством значений через запятую>
  end loop;
  l_sql='select * from table where name in ('||l_txt||')';
  execute immediate l_sql into tableRow;
  ...
end;
```

В топе нагрузки всплывает парс этого запроса. Хочется параметризовать этот запрос, но не понятно, как сделать это. Все усложняется тем, что заранее не известно, из скольки значений сформируется `l_sql`.

Идеи которые пока приходили в голову:

1) Создать временную таблицу и ее заполнять вместо генерации переменной `l_sql` и в запросе обращаться к таблице. Кажется не лучшим решением заменять парс запроса на запись во временную таблицу и ее чтение.

2) Динамически формировать блок с нужным количеством переменных и уже их подставлять. Но тоже кажется не очень хорошим решением.

Возможно существует более хорошее решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать не динамически формируемый запрос. Список формируете как и раньше, текстом, через запятую в переменную `l_txt`. Запрос выглядит так:

```
select *
  from table T,
       xmltable(l_txt) X
 where T.name=trim(X.column_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

В старом обсуждении у Тома Кайта ([How can I do a variable "in list"](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3A%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425)) предлагается следующий вариант.

1. Создать тип

   ```
   create or replace type myTableType as table of varchar2 (255)
   ```
2. Создать функцию

   ```
   create or replace function in_list(p_string in varchar2) return myTableType as
     l_string long default p_string || ',';
     l_data   myTableType := myTableType();
     n        number;
   begin
     loop
       exit when l_string is null;
       n := instr(l_string, ',');
       l_data.extend;
       l_data(l_data.count) := ltrim(rtrim(substr(l_string, 1, n - 1)));
       l_string := substr(l_string, n + 1);
     end loop;
     return l_data;
   end;
   ```
3. Затем можно заменить динамический запрос на что-то вроде:

   ```
   select *
     from table
    where name in (select *
                     from TABLE(select cast(in_list(l_txt) as mytableType)
                                 from dual))
   ```

Это избавит от разбора запроса при каждом выполнении, но нужно будет оценить изменения производительности в новом запросе.

Еще один вариант был предложен в похожем вопросе по SQL Server ([Parameterize an SQL IN clause](http://Parameterize%20an%20SQL%20IN%20clause)):

1. Меняем формат `l_txt` с `abc,def,ghi` на `|abc|def|ghi|` где «`|`» —
   разделитель, не встречающийся в `name`:
2. Пишем запрос наоборот:

   ```
   select *
   from table
   where l_txt like '%|'||name||'|%'
   ```

Этот подход также избавляет от динамического запроса и также заменяет запрос на менее оптимальный.

Comment: Первый вариант выглядит тяжелым. А второй к сожалению не получится использовать, так как при таком `like` не получится использовать индекс по таблице. За сам вариант спасибо, интересный подход